# App cannot run on real iOS device but can run on the simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

Previously, my app works fine on my iPad, However, yesterday Xcode started giving me this error as shown in the screenshot.[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Read the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a provisioning profile in developer.apple.com if you dont have one yet.

then add the device to this provisioning profile by:

1. Login to your developer portal through developer.apple.com
2. Add the UDID in devices (you can retrieve it from Itunes from your
   mac)
3. Go back to XCode, open up the Organizer and select
   "Provisioning Profiles", ensure that "Automatic Device Provisioning"
   is checked on the top right pane, then click on the "Refresh"
   button, and magically all your devices set in the provisioning
   portal will be automatically added.

After doing these steps try again run your app it should work